# CakePhp foreach saving only last value in array

Tags: arrays, loops, cakephp, foreach

I have a problem, right now Im using this foreach loop on CakePhp on which I want to add all the values which are still not on the table for the respecting user. To give a little more context, the user has a menu. And the admin can select which one to add for the user to use. On the next code I receive a array with the menus which will be added as so:

```
//This is what comes on the ['UserMenuAccessibility'] array:
    Array ( [menu_accessibility_id2] => 2 [menu_accessibility_id3] => 3 [menu_accessibility_id4] => 4 [menu_accessibility_id5] => 5 [menu_accessibility_id8] => 8 )
```

I get the ids of the menus which want to be added to the table for the user to use. And I use the next code to add the menus to the table if they are not there still:

```
//I check if the array has something cause it can come with no ids.    
if (!(isset($this->request->data['UserMenuAccessibility']))) {
        $this->request->data['UserMenuAccessibility'] = array();
    }

    $UserMenuAccessibility = $this->request->data['UserMenuAccessibility'];

    foreach ($UserMenuAccessibility as $key => $value) {

        $conditions = array(
            'UserMenuAccessibility.menu_accessibility_id' => $value, 
            'UserMenuAccessibility.users_id' => $id
        );

        if ($this->User->UserMenuAccessibility->hasAny($conditions)) {

        }  else {
            $valuemenu['UserMenuAccessibility']['users_id'] = $id;
            $valuemenu['UserMenuAccessibility']['menu_accessibility_id'] = $value;
            if ($this->User->UserMenuAccessibility->save($valuemenu)) {

            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }
    }
```

For some reason the array is only saving the last new id which is not on the table and not the rest. For example if I have menu 1 and 2 and add 3 and 4 only 4 gets added to the table. For some reason I cant add all the missing menu ids to the table. Any ideas why this is happening?

Thanks for the help on advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your code will save each item, but each call to `save()` is overwriting the last entry added as `$this->User->UserMenuAccessibility->id` is set after the first save and will be used for subsequent saves. Try calling `$this->User->UserMenuAccessibility->create()` before each save to ensure that the model data is reset and ready to accept new data:-

```
$valuemenu['UserMenuAccessibility']['users_id'] = $id;
$valuemenu['UserMenuAccessibility']['menu_accessibility_id'] = $value;
$this->User->UserMenuAccessibility->create();
if ($this->User->UserMenuAccessibility->save($valuemenu)) {
}
```

Comment: But of course! XD Its really weird cause I had this piece of code on another site I build. And it worked well there. I dunno why it didnt work on this side. I thank you so much for pointing that out! It work like a charm :D

Answer (score 1):

In cakephp 2.0 $this->Model->create() create work fine. But if you are using cakephp version 3 or greater then 3. Then follow the below code

```
$saveData['itemId']             = 1;

$saveData['qty']                = 2;

$saveData['type']               = '0';

$saveData['status']             = 'active';

$saveData = $this->Model->newEntity($saveData);

$this->Model->save($materialmismatch);
```

**In normal case we use patchEntity**

```
$this->Model->patchEntity($saveData, $this->request->data);
```

It will only save last values of array so you have to use newEntity() with data

Answer (score 0):

In cakephp3, [`patchEntity()`](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/saving-data.html#validation-and-patchentity) is normally used. However, when using it for inserting-new/updating entries in a foreach loop, I too saw that it only saves the last element of the array.

What worked for me was using `patchEntities()`, which as explained in the `patchEntity()` doc, is used for patching multiple entities at once.

So simplifying and going by the original code sample to handle multiple entities, it could be:

```
$userMenuAccessibilityObject = TableRegistry::get('UserMenuAccessibility');
foreach ($UserMenuAccessibility as $key => $value) {
    $userMenuAccessibility = $userMenuAccessibilityObject->get($value);//get original individual entity if exists
    $userMenuAccessibilities[] = $userMenuAccessibility;
    $dataToPatch = [
        'menu_accessibility_id' => $value,
        'users_id' => $id
    ]//store corresponding entity data in array for patching after foreach
    $userMenuAccessibilitiesData[] = $dataToPatch;
}
$userMenuAccessibilities = $userMenuAccessibilityObject->patchEntities($userMenuAccessibilities, $userMenuAccessibilities);
if ($userMenuAccessibilityObject->saveMany($requisitions)) {
} else {
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The users could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
}
```

Note: I haven't made it handle if entity doesn't exist, create a new one and resume. That can be done with a simple if condition.